# change block position in magento

Tags: xml, magento, block, move

Hi i need to show the related products on product view page and below main product image.It was showing in the sidebar initially than change its position in catalog.xml from right bloch to content block

in catelog.xml it was like this

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

now i have move this to main content block

```
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

but it displays in the end of page means above footer, is there a way tht i can display this in view page any where please suggest some ideas thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<catalog_product_view>

<reference name="product.info">

    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="product.info.media" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

use above code will display related product after media

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`$this->getChildHtml('yourBlockName');`

inside the `frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/view.phtml` template file.

Make sure you have injected the block in `layout.xml` as well.